# T-SQL XML Modify Syntax Dynamically set tag using a variable

Tags: xml, t-sql

Using 'modify' in SQL to insert an xml variable which contains a new tag in between an existing xml variable. I have managed to get it working by hard-coding [5] but I am trying to dynamically set the value where the tag should be. Below example. I want to dynamically set the [5] to be @TotalNo variable. I am trying to calculate where the Subject is and only insert the new tag after that.

Below works but its hard-coded the number 5, but this value could change depending on different examples as sometimes where may not be a CC therefore the value would be 4 in that case.

@TotalNo variable contains the number I need to put in, but dont know how to set it in this after (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue)**[5]**

```
 DECLARE @comment XML = '<ParameterValue>
        <Name>Comment</Name>
        <Value>Test Report</Value>
    </ParameterValue>'

DECLARE @XMLSettings XML = '<ParameterValues>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>TO</Name>
        <Value>aaa</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>CC</Name>
        <Value>bbb</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>IncludeReport</Name>
        <Value>True</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>RenderFormat</Name>
        <Value>PDF</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>Subject</Name>
        <Value>New Report</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>IncludeLink</Name>
        <Value>False</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue >
        <Name>Priority</Name>
        <Value>NORMAL</Value>
    </ParameterValue>

</ParameterValues>'

DECLARE @TotalNo INT
SET @TotalNo = @XMLSettings.value('count(/ParameterValues/ParameterValue)', 'INT')

SET @TotalNo = @TotalNo - 2

SET @XMLSettings.modify('insert sql:variable("@comment") after (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue)[5]')


select @XMLSettings
```

Tried the following:

```
SET @XMLSettings.modify('insert sql:variable("@comment") after (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue)[sql:variable("@TotalNo")]')
```

but get this error:

> Msg 2226, Level 16, State 1, Line 44 XQuery [modify()]: The target of
>   'insert' must be a single node, found
>   'element(ParameterValue,xdt:untyped) *'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rest is okay for you, you can simply solve the existing approach by changing

```
SET @ExtensionSettings.modify('insert sql:variable("@comment") after (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue)[sql:variable("@TotalNo")]')
```

to

```
SET @ExtensionSettings.modify('insert sql:variable("@comment") after (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue)[sql:variable("@TotalNo")][1]')
```

The only difference is the additional `[1]`. This **must** be a singleton, but the engine is not able to predict the content of the handed in variable.

But this would do the same without any external variable

```
SET @XMLSettings.modify('insert sql:variable("@comment") after (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue)[count(/ParameterValues/ParameterValue)-2][1]')
```

And this would place the comment behind "Subject" wihtout any counting

```
SET @XMLSettings.modify('insert sql:variable("@comment") after (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name/text()="Subject"])[1]')
```

You can use a declared variable (...`ParameterValue[Name/text()=sq:variable("@target")`) to pass in the node you want to be the predecessor.